# setting doctype breaks my css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, doctype

And it can be any doctype, html5 or any of the html4's.

Specifically, if I don't set a doctype everything is fine.  If I set a doctype, the colors set as such:

```
  #Engine {
    color:Sienna;
  }

  #Gameplay {
    color:Green;
  }

  #Art {
    color:Chocolate;
  }
```

are ignored.  A few other tags are also ignored, mainly relating to id's I think.  I can set the font size to be as large as the screen and nothing happens.

The css passed ok with the css validator, as did the html with the html validator (*when* I inserted the doctype, not before).

Also the javascript that normally runs without a hitch breaks, failing to find the "offset" method of a jquery node...

Effect is same in chrome and firefox (latest versions).  Won't load at all in internet explorer with or without doctype, but that's for a separate topic...

Comment: could you post your full code or a jsFiddle?

Comment: Use hexcodes instead of names, there are only 16 valid names, others may or may not be supported by the browser. When you add a doctype, the browser will not fix errors, you need to show more code. make a bare bones example that shows the problems.

Comment: You can probably quickly check that the issue does not depend on color names; if you set them with numbers, the problem remains. The reason is that the problem is elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probable cause is that in your markup, you have spelled the `id` values differently from the spelling of the `id` selectors. If you have `id="engine"` in markup, then the element does not match the selector `#Engine` in “Standards Mode”. In Quirks Mode, it apparently does. (This seems to apply to newest released versions of Chrome, Firefox, and IE.)

The solution is to make sure that you use exactly the same spelling in each occurrence of an identifier defined by an `id` attribute. The [definition of `id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id) in the HTML 4.01 spec clearly designates it as Case Sensitive.

Comment: Thanks man.  That was exactly the issue.  I kinda new about it, but somehow overlooked several inconsistencies...